# images surrounding container to follow the container regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

Here's the live link of the my project - http://sunwaycleanairproject.com/pledge

I have 3 images placed around the corners of the tiles -

```
 <div class="back-top-right"></div>
 <div class="back-bottom-right"></div>
 <div class="back-bottom-left"></div>

.master-container .back-top-right {
position: absolute;
top: 2%;
left: 78%;
background: url(../../images/27.png) center center no-repeat;
width: 248px;
height: 214px;
content: ' ';
}

.master-container .back-bottom-left {
left: -22px;
bottom: 40px;
background: url(../../images/28.png) center center no-repeat;
width: 248px;
height: 253px;
}

.master-container .back-bottom-left {
left: -22px;
bottom: 40px;
background: url(../../images/28.png) center center no-repeat;
width: 248px;
height: 253px;
}
```

How can improve my css so that the images will move according to the container and stay in place?

I'm working on a 15 inch macbook pro screen, and fullscreen it looks good. If I viewed this website on different screen sizes(larger ones especially), these images will be all over the place. I want them to always stay in place, always at the corners of the grid container.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of your screen view.

Comment: Please be more specific and show all related code you have at the moment. Clearly show/specify which 3 pictures you're referring to and then we'll see if we can help

Comment: @Mers I included the classes of the images and the link for others to view it more clearly. On the link given there are only 3 images surrounding the grid container. I guess I'll include the css as well. See updated

Comment: @MSTQNB I included Live preview on my question

Comment: @Mers my problem right now is that when this on bigger screen the 3 images are placed all over the place and not at the edges of the grid container.

Comment: @rory-h, looking over your live code, it seems that your image divs(`back-top-right, back-bottom-left and -right`), as well as your `square-container` div, are nested inside the `content` div. This `content` div has the position set to relative and has no fixed width. Your image divs have `position: absolute`, which means that the image divs are position relative to their parent, which is the`content` div, not the `square-container` div, which contains your 'tiles'. When a browser window is adjusted, and being that `content` div doesn't have set width, the images move relative to its edges.

Comment: @Mers I've set a definite width and height for content div. but my images are just way out of place when I tested the page on screens bigger than 1440px in width. been trying to adjust this for hours and I'm running out of ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Please see http://imgur.com/a/vrKpE
According to the develop tools, there is no width set on your `content` div.

When I set width on your `content` div using developer tools and it locks down the images, even when i resize the window across multiple monitors. Please check your `content` div properties again. According to the developer tools, width is not explicitly set for the `content` div.

Answer (score 0):

make the size fixed for some screens. Mediaqueries will help